# MiKTeX in Ubuntu 14.04: Could NOT find CURL

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, latex, curl

I am trying to install MiKTeX in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am downloading the dependencies one by one, but below is where I got stuck:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:659 (message):
  /usr/bin/qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" but
  QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the
  target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:347 (find_package)

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:54 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:354 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Downloads/2.9/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/Downloads/2.9/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As for CURL, I do have it. When I put `curl -V` I get the following:

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Also, what QT should I install?

Comment: You are bumping into several problems simultaneously. First of all, the only dependencies required by MikTex are `build-essential` and `libcurl3-openssl-dev`. Secondly, you seem to have a non packaged version of CURL; from the repositories I got 7.23.1 for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

MikTeX is not packaged for Ubuntu, but it is fairly easy to install if you follow [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiktexPackageManager).

Start by removing any packages you may have installed by hand (e.g. CURL). Then install the dependencies from the repositories:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl3-openssl-dev`

Configure and compile (inside the MikTeX source folder):

`./configure && make`

And finally install it:

`sudo make install`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I installed the libs you advised but when I put `./configure && make`, it says bash: ./configure: No such file or directory. When I type `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"` as instructed by MiKTeX, the CURL error disappeared but I get the error `Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)`. Even though I have it!

Comment: Make sure you have the package `libzip2` installed from the repositories and try again.